# Dutch Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen-visas

I’m leaving for The Netherlands in 2 weeks but I was meant to be staying with my girlfriend, who ended things a week ago... She says she’s going to the embassy to inform them of the change of plans but the say there will be consequences if she pulls the application.

I have booked accommodation for the first 3 nights in Amsterdam and then going to back pack and meet up with some friends.

I already have my visa, can this affect my trip or lead to my visa being revoked ?

Comment: Some important details seem to be missing. Why would your girlfriend have any effect on your visa? Did you say you would be staying with her? Or did you say she would be paying for your trip? Or something else?

Comment: So in the application she filled out a form saying my accommodation would be covered by her as I would be staying with her. Obviously now we are no longer together and she wants to go to the embassy to revoke the application where she said I will be staying with her

Comment: It seems unlikely this will be a problem if you can show bookings. Maybe you could get a letter from those friends you will be staying with, also.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant rule is section 32(2) of the [Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810):

> A visa shall be revoked where it becomes evident that the conditions for issuing it are no longer met. A visa shall in principle be revoked by the competent authorities of the Member State which issued it. A visa may be revoked by the competent authorities of another Member State, in which case the authorities of the Member State that issued the visa shall be informed of such revocation.

So what it comes down to is whether the fact that you would be staying with your (then) girlfriend was a determining factor in the decision to approve your visa. This would usually only be the case if you couldn't have afforded the trip otherwise.

Even in the worst case, it seems to be unlikely that the Dutch authorities would revoke your visa without communicating with you first. But it is possible that they'd put a note on the visa/passport such that border guards would be more likely to probe into your means of subsistence when you enter. So you might want to be extra sure you're traveling with good documentation of your plans for food and lodging during the planned visit.